# When is native GIF support coming to Android?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, images

When I try to view a GIF in Whatsapp, or the default Android Gallery app - GIFs do not autoplay.

Why is this? When is native support for GIFs coming to Android?

Comment: Are you sure that Whatsapp send animated GIFs correctly?

Comment: I think that WhatsApp doesn't support GIFs yet, when I received one it was displayed as a still image. But Android does support GIFs, if you download one from the net it should be displayed just fine (at least by Google Photos, but many other app support them). If yours doesn't, is probably because WA converted it to an image only.

Answer (score 0):

To till date now, Android OS don't have native support to run GIF files. For such approach they demand to use a GIF Player or any Media Player who is aware to run GIF (stack of images animated).

E.g. Gallery app, Photos app etc they have features to play gif files.